# How can varying sentence length create a specific tone or mood in a creative writing piece?

Tags: creative-writing

On one hand, I was told that we should always use short sentences, but on the other hand I was also told that shorter sentences is good for short-paced actions, and longer sentences can be good for things like when there's a situation where the character is contemplating something, so I was wondering if there are other situations where I should use longer sentences to create a specific tone or mood.

Answer (score 4):

I would use long (and involved) sentences when you, as the author, want to slow things down.

If I were writing about a chase through a forest and wanted to convey urgency, I would use mostly short sentences; they are quick and easy to consume. All the trees in the forest are the same.

On the other hand, if I were writing about a nature walk through that same forest and wanted to convey a oneness with life (with seasonal overtones and references to poems, known and not so well known), I would use longer sentences with several clauses; these sentences require more cognitive processing to consume. Each tree in the forest has a story to tell.

If I were writing about a surveillance operation in that same forest and wanted to convey suspense (or horror), I would use a mixture of sentence lengths; for example, "She paused a moment, panting quietly as she waited and wondering if the crack of the twig she had inadvertently stepped on would alert the target. Then she rushed to the next tree." Some of the trees are big enough to hide behind and others are not.

It is all about how fast you want the reader to process your writing.